# Capture Video Frames sample code for IOS 7.0 and up

Tags: ios

I am trying to come up with IOS 7 code for this Apple Q&A code on how to capture video frames: [AppleQ&A1702](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1702/_index.html)

So far I think that I have replaced the deprecated minFrameDuration correctly with is code:

```
// If you wish to cap the frame rate to a known value, such as 2 fps, set minFrameDuration.
//output.minFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 2); //deprecated
[device setActiveVideoMinFrameDuration:CMTimeMake(1, 2)];  //new in IOS7
[device setActiveVideoMaxFrameDuration:CMTimeMake(1, 2)];
```

But, I can not run the code because I get a 'No interface error' for setSession on this line:

```
// Assign session to an ivar.
[self setSession:session];
```

Also, I get an incompatible type warning on this line:

```
[output setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:queue];
```

I believe there are simple answers for this error and warning but after lots of searching I am stumped.
Can someone help me figure out why I get this error and warning straight from Apple sample code? Thanks Carmen

[EDIT1] I don't think I was quite there with my deprecated minFrameDuration fix and it may be that the setSession method is NOT necessary. I am trying to piece together cut and paste code that works to capture images from a video at a specified frame rate for IOS7  App that does NOT need to run on less than 7.0.  I am temporarily putting the captured images in a UIImageView on my storyboard.

It shouldn't be this hard.

Here is the whole code section I have so far but it still does not trigger the captureOutput Method after I call setupCaptureSession from my viewDidLoad and the incompatible type warning mentioned above still exists, can anyone see what is wrong (I am still a newbie so be nice :)

```
// Create and configure a capture session and start it running
- (void)setupCaptureSession
{
    NSError *error = nil;

    // Create the session
    AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];

    // Configure the session to produce resolution for video frames
    session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh;

    // Find a suitable AVCaptureDevice
    AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    // Create a device input with the device and add it to the session.
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device
                                                                                              error:&error];
    if (!input) {
        // Handling the error appropriately.
    }
    [session addInput:input];

    // Create a VideoDataOutput and add it to the session
    AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *output = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
    [session addOutput:output];

    // Configure your output.
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("myQueue", NULL);
    [output setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:queue];

    // Specify the pixel format
    output.videoSettings =
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:
     [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA]
                                         forKey:(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey];


    // If you wish to cap the frame rate to a known value, such as 2 fps, set
    // minFrameDuration.
    //output.minFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 2); //deprecated


    //AVCaptureConnection *conn = [output connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    //if (conn.supportsVideoMinFrameDuration)  // these are deprecated in IOS7
    //  conn.videoMinFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1,2);
    //if (conn.supportsVideoMaxFrameDuration)
    //  conn.videoMaxFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1,2);

    NSError *error2;
    [device lockForConfiguration:&error2];
    if (error2 == nil) {
        if (device.activeFormat.videoSupportedFrameRateRanges){
            [device setActiveVideoMinFrameDuration:CMTimeMake(1, 2)];
            [device setActiveVideoMaxFrameDuration:CMTimeMake(1, 2)];
        }else{
            //handle condition
        }
    }else{
        // handle error2
    }
    [device unlockForConfiguration];


    // Start the session running to start the flow of data
    [session startRunning];

    // Assign session to an ivar.
    //[self setSession:session];  //not sure why need this, can't find code that works for it
}

- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput
didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
       fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"captureOutput: didOutputSampleBufferFromConnection");

    // Create a UIImage from the sample buffer data
    UIImage *image = [self imageFromSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //< Add your code here that uses the image >
        [self.imageView setImage:image];
        [self.view setNeedsDisplay];}
        );
}

// Create a UIImage from sample buffer data
- (UIImage *) imageFromSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef) sampleBuffer
{
    // Get a CMSampleBuffer's Core Video image buffer for the media data
    CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
    // Lock the base address of the pixel buffer
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);

    // Get the number of bytes per row for the pixel buffer
    void *baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);

    // Get the number of bytes per row for the pixel buffer
    size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer);
    // Get the pixel buffer width and height
    size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);
    size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);

    // Create a device-dependent RGB color space
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    // Create a bitmap graphics context with the sample buffer data
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress, width, height, 8,
                                                                bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
    // Create a Quartz image from the pixel data in the bitmap graphics context
    CGImageRef quartzImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    // Unlock the pixel buffer
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);

    // Free up the context and color space
    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    // Create an image object from the Quartz image
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:quartzImage];

    // Release the Quartz image
    CGImageRelease(quartzImage);

    return (image);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So it appears that the key to this issue was Apples instructions to 'Assign session to an ivar' and then providing a call to a method that they did not provide code for.

Since I am new and use ARC I was hoping not to have to understand synthesis/ivars and I still don't.

But, here is code that works as basic capture code (my whole viewController.).  Basically I had to declare session after my Import lines in my viewController.m

Maybe someone can explain what I did but I am considering this solved for now (still not sure about the incompatible type warning mentioned in the question):

```
#import "CJKViewController.h"

AVCaptureSession *session;

@interface CJKViewController ()

@end

@implementation CJKViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    // Create the session

    [self setupCaptureSession];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}







// Create and configure a capture session and start it running
- (void)setupCaptureSession
{
    NSError *error = nil;

//  AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];

    // Configure the session to produce lower resolution video frames, if your
    // processing algorithm can cope. We'll specify medium quality for the
    // chosen device.
    session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh;

    // Find a suitable AVCaptureDevice
    AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    // Create a device input with the device and add it to the session.
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device
                                                                                              error:&error];
    if (!input) {
        // Handling the error appropriately.
    }
    [session addInput:input];

    // Create a VideoDataOutput and add it to the session
    AVCaptureVideoDataOutput *output = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];
    [session addOutput:output];

    // Configure your output.
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("myQueue", NULL);
    [output setSampleBufferDelegate:self queue:queue];

    // Specify the pixel format
    output.videoSettings =
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:
     [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA]
                                         forKey:(id)kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey];


    // If you wish to cap the frame rate to a known value, such as 2 fps, set
    // minFrameDuration.
    //output.minFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1, 2); //deprecated


    //AVCaptureConnection *conn = [output connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    //if (conn.supportsVideoMinFrameDuration)
    //  conn.videoMinFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1,2);
    //if (conn.supportsVideoMaxFrameDuration)
    //  conn.videoMaxFrameDuration = CMTimeMake(1,2);

    NSError *error2;
    [device lockForConfiguration:&error2];
    if (error2 == nil) {
        if (device.activeFormat.videoSupportedFrameRateRanges){
            [device setActiveVideoMinFrameDuration:CMTimeMake(1, 2)];
            [device setActiveVideoMaxFrameDuration:CMTimeMake(1, 2)];
        }
    }else{
        // handle error2
    }
    [device unlockForConfiguration];


    // Start the session running to start the flow of data
    [session startRunning];

    // Assign session to an ivar.
    //[self setSession:session];
}

- (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput
didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
       fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"captureOutput: didOutputSampleBufferFromConnection");

    // Create a UIImage from the sample buffer data
    UIImage *image = [self imageFromSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //< Add your code here that uses the image >
        [self.imageView setImage:image];
        [self.view setNeedsDisplay];}
        );
}

// Create a UIImage from sample buffer data
- (UIImage *) imageFromSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef) sampleBuffer
{
    // Get a CMSampleBuffer's Core Video image buffer for the media data
    CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
    // Lock the base address of the pixel buffer
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);

    // Get the number of bytes per row for the pixel buffer
    void *baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);

    // Get the number of bytes per row for the pixel buffer
    size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer);
    // Get the pixel buffer width and height
    size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);
    size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);

    // Create a device-dependent RGB color space
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    // Create a bitmap graphics context with the sample buffer data
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress, width, height, 8,
                                                                bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst);
    // Create a Quartz image from the pixel data in the bitmap graphics context
    CGImageRef quartzImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    // Unlock the pixel buffer
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);

    // Free up the context and color space
    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    // Create an image object from the Quartz image
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:quartzImage];

    // Release the Quartz image
    CGImageRelease(quartzImage);

    return (image);
}

@end
```